# Optional param for Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to Airflow. I need to create a dag, and one pf the params can be optional. I am not sure on how to specify that. Maybe this is more of a python question...
Could anyone advise?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Param must have a default value.
So incase you trigger the DAG without a specific parameter then Airflow will add it with default value.

If you want to ignore this param in any condition then you can put a unique value in the default that helps you understand the status of this param.

For example you can put empty string in the default

```
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Param
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

with DAG(
    "demo",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    params={
        "test": Param("", type="string")
    },
    tags=["demo"],
) as dag:

    def print_task(**context):
        value = context["params"]["test"]
        if value :
            print(value)
        else:
            print("no value")

    start_dag = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")
    task1 = PythonOperator(task_id="print", python_callable=print_task)
    start_dag >> task1
```

Comment: Is there any way to *not* have a default value? I want my dag run to abort if it is triggered without being given an explicit param value, not keep running with some mystery default.

Comment: @BenFarmer yes you can. use context["dag_run"].conf which return only params that were filled.

Comment: Oh you mean just leave them out of the 'params' argument altogether? Hmm ok will try it.

Answer (score 1):

I've accomplished to have "" as default, but then make it not complain that it is required by changing the type from simple "string" to:

```
type=["null", "string"]
```